# Show Events list Google Play Games

Tags: android, google-play-games

I created some events in Google Play Developer, and i want to start an Activity that shows all the events. Is there any way to do that?

For quests i do this:

```
public void showQuests() {
    Intent questsIntent = Games.Quests.getQuestsIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
        Quests.SELECT_ALL_QUESTS);
    startActivityForResult(questsIntent, 0);
}
```

but i can't find the Events intent to show a list of all the Events

Answer (score 1):

Good thing this is well documented in Google's [Adding Events and Quests to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quests#before_you_begin)

The following snippet shows how you can query Google Play games services for the list of all events for your game:

```
// EventCallback is a subclass of ResultCallback; use this to handle the
// query results

EventCallback ec = new EventCallback();

// Load all events tracked for your game
com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult<Events.LoadEventsResult>
        pr = Games.Events.load(mGoogleApiClient, true);
pr.setResultCallback(ec);
```

If the call is successful, the system triggers the ResultCallback object in your app. You should handle the query results in the onResult() method:

```
class EventCallback implements ResultCallback {
    // Handle the results from the events load call
    public void onResult(com.google.android.gms.common.api.Result result) {
        Events.LoadEventsResult r = (Events.LoadEventsResult)result;
        com.google.android.gms.games.event.EventBuffer eb = r.getEvents();

        for (int i=0; i < eb.getCount(); i++) {
            // do something with the events retrieved
        }
        eb.close();
    }
}
```

Full samples are in this [repo](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/TrivialQuest2).